# Memory leak in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

What's the memory leak in the following script?

```
function postars(canvas) {
var _this = this,
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
_this.config = {
    star: {
        color: '#ffffff'
    },
    line: {
        color: '#ffffff',
        width: 0.1
    },
    position: {
        x: canvas.width * 0.5,
        y: canvas.height * 0.5
    },
    velocity: 0.1,
    length: 100,
    distance: 120,
    radius: 150,
    stars: []
};

function Star() {
    this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    this.vx = (_this.config.velocity - (Math.random() * 0.5));
    this.vy = (_this.config.velocity - (Math.random() * 0.5));
    this.radius = Math.random();
}
Star.prototype = {
    create: function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    },
    animate: function() {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < _this.config.length; i++) {
            var star = _this.config.stars[i];
            if (star.y < 0 || star.y > canvas.height) {
                star.vx = star.vx;
                star.vy = -star.vy;
            } else if (star.x < 0 || star.x > canvas.width) {
                star.vx = -star.vx;
                star.vy = star.vy;
            }
            star.x += star.vx;
            star.y += star.vy;
        }
    },
    line: function() {
        var length = _this.config.length,
            iStar, jStar, i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                iStar = _this.config.stars[i];
                jStar = _this.config.stars[j];
                if ((iStar.x - jStar.x) < _this.config.distance && (iStar.y - jStar.y) < _this.config.distance && (iStar.x - jStar.x) > -_this.config.distance && (iStar.y - jStar.y) > -_this.config.distance) {
                    if ((iStar.x - _this.config.position.x) < _this.config.radius && (iStar.y - _this.config.position.y) < _this.config.radius && (iStar.x - _this.config.position.x) > -_this.config.radius && (iStar.y - _this.config.position.y) > -_this.config.radius) {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(iStar.x, iStar.y);
                        ctx.lineTo(jStar.x, jStar.y);
                        ctx.stroke();
                        ctx.closePath();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
_this.createStars = function() {
    var length = _this.config.length,
        star, i;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        _this.config.stars.push(new Star());
        star = _this.config.stars[i];
        star.create();
    }
    star.line();
    star.animate();
};
_this.setCanvas = function() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
};
_this.setContext = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = _this.config.star.color;
    ctx.strokeStyle = _this.config.line.color;
    ctx.lineWidth = _this.config.line.width;
};
_this.loop = function(callback) {
    callback();
    reqAnimFrame(function() {
        _this.loop(function() {
            callback();
        });
    });
};
_this.bind = function() {
    $(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        _this.config.position.x = e.pageX;
        _this.config.position.y = e.pageY;
    });
};
_this.init = function() {
    _this.setCanvas();
    _this.setContext();
    _this.loop(function() {
        _this.createStars();
    });
    _this.bind();
};
return _this;
}
var reqAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||     window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||     window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
};
```

It's working for a few hours and then Chrome crashes (displays an error page saying something went wrong) or outputs "stack overflow" to console.

Comment: Play around with Chrome Developer Tools (Hit F12). Especially try the "Profiles" function. Take two Heap Snapshots and compare them. You should see which variables are growing...

Comment: Please share more information about your problem. What are you trying to achieve? What's the expected result? Particularly, you can try to explain what's the expected behavior of `_this.loop`, which is recursive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not to use new Star() in a function's parameter, instead of that do:

```
var newStar = new Star()
_this.config.stars.push(newStar)
newStar = null
```

And to modify the code not to create new stars continously.